# Getting COPY Failed: stat when trying to copy package.json file in Docker on DigitalOcean Droplet

Tags: node.js, docker, github, containers, digital-ocean

I am trying to create a docker container off of a Docker droplet in DigitalOcean. I am trying to use Git clone to run a Node.js app.
I am getting the error COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder249248811/package.json: no such file or directory and I am not sure why. I have tried to RUN cd, tried changing the WORKdir, tried changing the path in the COPY.
I am running the build command from the /root folder which is where I have created the dockerfile.

```
FROM node:12.18.3
 #RUN mkdir /root/live \
  #  cd  /root/live \

RUN  git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/Portfolio.git
WORKDIR .
RUN cd  /Portfolio
COPY  package.json /Portfolio
COPY package-lock.json . /Portfolio
COPY . .
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["pm2", "start", "./bin/ww"]
```

Comment: Please consider, for this or your other question, to select an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COPY` copies files from the Docker *build context* (the directory named in the `docker build` command, frequently the directory containing the Dockerfile) into the image.  It doesn't copy files within an image.

You'll typically want to run this `git clone` command outside of Docker.  There are a couple of reasons for this: it lets you check the Dockerfile into the repository; it lets you build an image out of something you haven't committed yet; Docker layer caching doesn't prevent you from seeing changes in the source repository; you don't want your GitHub credentials from being visible in plain text in `docker history`.

I'd recommend this (fairly boilerplate) Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM node:12.18.3

# This also creates the directory if it doesn't exist.
# (This frequently is "/app".)
WORKDIR /Portfolio

# We ran `git clone` on the host outside of Docker.
# Copy in only the files we need to install dependencies.
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# Now copy in the rest of the application.
# (`node_modules` should be included in `.dockerignore`.)
COPY . ./
# RUN npm build

# Standard metadata to start the application.
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["pm2", "start", "./bin/ww"]
# (Do you actually need a process manager inside a Docker container?)
# CMD ["node", "./bin/ww"]
```

The other problem you're encountering here is that each `RUN` command runs in its own isolated environment; changes to the current working directory or to the environment are lost at the end of each `RUN` command.  You need to use the `WORKDIR` directive to change directories, not `RUN cd ...`.

If you wanted to stick with running `git clone` inside the Dockerfile, you need to change the `WORKDIR` to what got checked out, but once you've done this, all the files are there and you don't need to `COPY` anything (or `RUN cp ...` to move them around within the image).

```sh
FROM node:12.18.3
WORKDIR /
# Remember, `docker history` will show this line exactly as here,
# including the credentials.
RUN git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/Portfolio.git

# Change directories into what got checked out.
WORKDIR /Portfolio
# All of the files are already there, so we only need to
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["pm2", "start", "./bin/ww"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, this has provided a lot of insight and detailed that I was missing. I am going to try your suggestions. I am going to try and clone in the dockerfile to just get started, but once it's up and running ill change it.  in regards to pm2 I am using that on my main droplet, but forgot that my git doesn't have any of those files, so the regular node cmd ill use. Thank you for taking the time to write out that response.

Comment: I changed my Dockerfile to look like the bottom example you did, the image did build (yay!), but another issue. I ran docker build -d -p 3000:3000 main(name of the image) and it gives me a container code, but when I run docker ps there is no container there, so I add tail -f /dev/null and the container runs, but when I go to <droplet i.p>:3000 it says refused to connect. Thank you for your time.

Comment: If the main container command is `tail`, that's not a network server and it will never listen on a network socket.

Comment: How do i get my container to sustain itself? after I do the docker run command it doesn't show up in docker ps.

Comment: I figured it out, I appreciate it. I used docker logs and found it I did a typo. You have been a fantastic help, I appreciate your time today. So Node apps either use pm2 or forever, but with docker I suppose you don't need those? unless you want to have the functionality of automatic server restart?